# "phablet-flash: error: too few arguments" when installing Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am using galaxy nexus yakjuux variant, I have converted it to yakju now since the basic requirements given for installing ubuntu touch was to have yakju or takju. I am running 4.3 android now, I have unlocked the bootloader by the above process mentioned but when I execute `phablet-flash -b` it gives me below error:

```
usage: phablet-flash [-h] ...
phablet-flash: error: too few arguments
```

I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

Also,some extra info: when I execute the `adb` devices command it doesn't show the offline mode as mentioned [on the guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install/).

Answer (score 2):

As of **version 1.0** (of phablet-tools) the syntax you need changes to:

**`phablet-flash cdimage-touch -b`**

---

See: **`phablet-flash -h`** OR http://sergiusens.github.io/posts/updates-to-phablet-flash.html

Verify what version you have with: **`dpkg -s phablet-tools | grep Version`**

*This new version definitely works for **Nexus 7** and **Nexus 10**, but I have not yet tried with **Galaxy Nexus**.*

Answer (score 1):

The installation instructions specify to include `cdimage-touch`, `cdimage-legacy`, `ubuntu-system` or `community` while executing phablet-flash, so the error is expected since you didn't provide all the necessary arguments. The correct way is either of this according to your system:

```
phablet-flash community -b
phablet-flash ubuntu-system -b
phablet-flash cdimage-legacy -b
phablet-flash cdimage-touch -b
```

Remember that **this will wipe the contents of the device so ensure you have made a back-up.** For a list of difference between each of the images is [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/342303/169736).

Source:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Step_4_-%3Ci%3EDownloading%3C/i%3E.26_Deploying_Image_to_Device

Comment: There's not a lot of information on the official page as to what the difference between those four are.

Comment: ubuntu-system is the new "read only" image. cdimage-legacy is the old original image which has Ubuntu booting in a container on an Android kernel. cdimage-touch is also known as the "flipped" image which has Android components/drivers booting in a container under an Ubuntu kernel. The community option is for images that canonical doesn't support (i.e. devices other than the nexus ones)

Comment: @popey I reverted your edit since the wiki specifically says that `-b` bootstrap is needed. Could you explain why bootstrap isn't needed in community and ubuntu-system images? I'm taking about [this one](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Step_4_-_Downloading_.26_Deploying_Image_to_Device)

Comment: @popey about your comment I recommend you to post that in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/342303/169736)

Comment: -b is not a valid argument as per my edit. http://paste.ubuntu.com/6097582/ - perhaps the wiki is wrong?