# What is the diference between the images of Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

In the [Ubuntu Touch installation page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Step_4_-_Downloading_.26_Deploying_Image_to_Device), there is this command that will wipe out the phone data and install Ubuntu Touch, but has 4 different options, what's the difference between each of them?

- cdimage-touch
- cdimage-legacy
- ubuntu-system
- community

> To install the Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview on your device, you will need to execute the command below. Please note, this will wipe the contents of the device so ensure you have made a back-up. To install and get updates, run the following command:
>
> ```
> phablet-flash (cdimage-touch|cdimage-legacy|ubuntu-system|community) -b
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cdimage-touch`

- Provisions the device with a CDimage build of Ubuntu Touch.

`cdimage-legacy`

- Provisions the device with legacy unflipped images. These images really shouldn't be used anymore, but it's a good time machine.

`ubuntu-system`

- Provisions the device with an Ubuntu Image Based Upgrade image. Refer to [this blog post](https://www.stgraber.org/2013/07/20/introducing-the-ubuntu-touch-image-based-upgrader/) or the [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ImageBasedUpgrades) describing it for more information.

`community`

- Provisions the device with a community supported build; community based images as described by [this blog post](https://daniel.holba.ch/blog/tag/porting/). In a nutshell, each porter provides a manifest of where their ports are located and the are provisioned to the target devices, this currently only works with recovery images that support extendedcommands. Support for openrecoverscript is one of the close targets.

**Source: http://sergiusens.github.io/posts/updates-to-phablet-flash.html**